Mutated more efficient breathing system
I decided to write my own story where parasites that change a person beyond recognition will appear. I have a problem with the design. The bottom line is that my monster (ex-man) has a shrinking chest. And here's the question: is there a way to reduce or replace the lungs without losing the quality of breathing? maybe the transformation of the lungs into another organ that will absorb more oxidants? Or even synthesizing its oxidizer inside the body, and then the body will simply need a food source.

Hello @Vazelin, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. Great first question. For future reference, keep in mind that the [help/dont-ask] prohibits giving your own answers and expecting more. Just the question, please. Thanks!

Counter-current lungs.
Our lungs end in dead-end sacs, where only about half the oxygen can be extracted, and that not terribly efficiently.
If the lungs were modified to pass air through them from one side to the other in a single direction, and run blood past the air tubes in the opposite direction to air flow, more oxygen could be extracted from the air in a smaller volume of lung than in normal human lungs.
Lungs can be far more volume-efficient... but I'll leave it up to the OP as to how this change would take place.

Thank you, it was very helpful

For a real-life example of counter-current respiration, check out birds. It does look like their anatomy could work for less chest compared to non-mutated humans.

Bird lungs are actually cross-current...

@MontyWild There seems to be some debate on the cross-current/counter-current aspect, but I do see their respiratory system fairly consistently described as having a unidirectional flow. That seems like what you were describing, but perhaps there's a technical difference I'm misunderstanding.

@Yeslek71 The article you linked is pretty much what I remember... direction of air flow through avian lungs makes no difference to oxygen uptake or carbon dioxide release, therefore they are functionally cross-current.  If they were counter-current, they'd be very much more efficient with air going in one direction than if it went in the other.

@MontyWild Sorry if I mischaracterized the avian respiratory system. I based that claim on the first website linked, which calls the "gas exchange" in birds counter-current. That might be different from the respiratory system as a whole, so thank you for clarifying that. I do still think avian anatomy could help spark ideas for a human with a shrinking chest. Having raised chickens, I can tell you their chest area was mostly crop, an organ humans don't need.

First of all, internally producing an oxidant and then use it to get energy doesn't make sense from the thermodynamic point of view.
We are then left with getting the oxidant from the outside with a respiratory apparatus which is shrinking in size. One way I can think of keeping up with it is the following: our current set up allows intake of fresh air only for about 50% of the breathing cycle, during the inhale phase, while during exhale phase there is no intake. If we could have a continuous flow, we could double up the intake and thus be able to afford a 50% loss of volume without negative consequences.
A way to do that would be to have inlet and outlet separated instead of using the same way. If the parasite do this, things can work out.

With such a rearrangement they either can't speak or you need to make some significant alterations to the vocal system as well .. not downplaying the answer, just observing that there may be other consequences unrelated to breathing.

thank you, I will take it into account when working on the design

Is this not essentially how avian/bird respiration works?

Yes, but hard. There is heart-lung machine, which can do that even by current human technology. Obviously small size is not a design goal of these machines. The thing is in the top right corner:

Very likely, similar things would be possible even in human lung or yet smaller size. Obviously doing this by nanotechnology (characteristic size is some atoms) is much better as doing the same on the cellular level (characteristic size might be a thousand times bigger).
However, these parasites are biological things and they should work on the cellular level. Fine, then do not make lungs in 1/1000 size, make lungs only in 1/3 size, task done.
A possible solution would be to increase the pressure, but only inside the lung. If you have 3x bigger pressure, you have 3x faster gas exchange. Although it needs energy, possibly a lot of energy.

Air sacs
Birds lungs anre incredibly efficent, uni-dirrectional flow is the important part, air only moves through the longs in one dirrection. small bird lungs together with air sacs  you get somthing similiar to the volume lost to mammal lungs.
But birds take up a lot more space with air sacs than they actually need because it helps with flight but they will work fine with less volume, (we see this in penguins). AND because air sacs don't all have to inflated at once to work they dount nood to take up as much space to move the same amount of air compared ot lungs. But birds do how a downside, their blood is a less efficent oxygen carrier than mammals, becasue they use nucleated red blood cells.
But you can combine the best of both.  Air sacs with a cross or counter current exchange in the lungs results in higher efficency, combined with mammalian blood you have a system more efficent than either birds or mammals. So it should be able to take up noticable less space than either. your only look ing at somthing like a 20-30% gain but thats nothing to sneeze at and probably the best you can gt useing realistic biology. Becasue it uses air sacs, the air sacs can be more spread out and not seperated by a diaphram so you gain a little space just that way. Down side, air acs need somthing tu pull aganst to they can't be in most othe lower torso unless you give them more ribs. you could give them a rigid torso like a bird with ribs all the way to the pelvis, or just a more rigid one by having more ribs, either will reduce flexibility in the lower back noticably.
As a bonus, if you shoot a hole through a bird and puncture its lung or air sac, they still work, albiet at reduced capacity, unlike mammalian lungs which stop working entirely.

great breakdown of bird breathing.
https://asknature.org/strategy/respiratory-system-facilitates-efficient-gas-exchange/
